# Create entity with both primary key and identity column in EF 6

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I already have a table with a `varchar` primary key. This is working fine with my current `.edmx` model.

Now I added an auto-increment identity column in that table. While I try to update the `.edmx`, that table is not being included in `.edmx`.

Can't I have a `varchar` PK column and an auto-increment identity column in the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [here's an example](http://rextester.com/VJT1877). The identity property has nothing to do with the PK. It just won't ever be null, obviously, and increments from the seed based off what ever you set.

```
create table myTable ( VC varchar(64) not null
                        ,primary key (VC)
                        )

insert into myTable
values
('something')
,('else')


select * 
from myTable

alter table myTable
add id int identity (1,1)


insert into myTable (VC)
values
('thirdColumn')


select * 
from myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not be the problem. Save your database table with the new column, delete and recreate .edmx. Hope it'll be done.