# partitioning data new data with existing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to updated index field for new records that has been added to the table.  Some of the records already have index, how can I update the new records with the next sequence of values?

```
Sample data:
    Index   INCIDENT_DT Incident_type   Event       CITY            COUNTRY
    1       1/2/16 0:00 Accident        Truck       Boston          NULL
    2       1/2/16 0:00 Accident        Car         Boston          NULL
    3       1/2/16 0:00 Accident        Ground      Sutton          USA
            1/2/16 0:00 Accident        NULL        NULL            NULL
            1/2/16 0:00 Accident        NULL        Chicago         NULL

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY  INCIDENT_DT order by  INCIDENT_DT) AS Index, INCIDENT_DT  
FROM  (select distinct  INCIDENT_DT, Incident_type, [event], INCIDENT_CITY, INCIDENT_COUNTRY from input ) r
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use the `UPDATE` function.

Comment: I would stop doing this manually, and apply the [identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) property to the Index field.

Comment: I wish there was a way to give @scsimon more than a like on the above comment. This process is insanity personified. It is a race condition and highly prone to error and/or collisions.

Comment: Sorry identity column is already employed and update will not work.   I'm trying to update the index over a group

Comment: What do you mean? Here's an example of just what you need to do. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47016218/6167855

Answer (score 1):

Hers one approach  is `UNION`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) [Index],* FROM 
(
    SELECT INCIDENT_DT, Incident_type,   [Event], CITY , COUNTRY FROM <table_name>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1/2/16 0:00' [INCIDENT_DT], 'Accident' [Incident_type], NULL [Event],    NULL  CITY, NULL COUNTRY
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1/2/16 0:00' [INCIDENT_DT], 'Accident' [Incident_type], NULL [Event],    'Chicago'  CITY, NULL COUNTRY
) A
```

**Result :**

```
Index   INCIDENT_DT Incident_type   Event   CITY    COUNTRY
1       1/2/16 0:00 Accident        Truck   Boston  NULL
2       1/2/16 0:00 Accident        Car     Boston  NULL
3       1/2/16 0:00 Accident        Ground  Sutton  USA 
4       1/2/16 0:00 Accident        NULL    NULL    NULL
5       1/2/16 0:00 Accident        NULL    Chicago NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Yogesh thanks for the idea. Never would have thought about unions.

This worked.

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY  INCIDENT_DT order by  grp, index, INCIDENT_DT) AS grp, index, INCIDENT_DT  
FROM  (select distinct 1 as grp, index, INCIDENT_DT, Incident_type, [event], INCIDENT_CITY, INCIDENT_COUNTRY from input where index is not null
union
select distinct 2 as grp, index, INCIDENT_DT, Incident_type, [event], INCIDENT_CITY, INCIDENT_COUNTRY from input where index is null
 ) r
```